# Inno Setup Function - Invalid Prototype

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm using Inno Setup for my installation and am adding the following function to the existing `[Code]` section:

```pascal
function Get64Or32: String;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
  begin
    Result := 'Program Files (x86)';
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := 'Program Files';
  end;
end;
```

I keep getting the following error:

> 10:41:08 Invalid prototype for 'Get64Or32'

I have tried several permutations including having the parenthesis after the function name but get the same error each time.

I'm attempting to use this from the `[Registry]` section to pinpoint the Java location:

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"JRE_HOME"; ValueData:"C:\{code:Get64or32}\Java\jre_1.8.0_151"; Flags: preservestringtype uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty; Permissions: users-modify;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look here [Pascal Scripting: Scripted Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) it explains it all. To quote:

> The syntax of a `{code:...}` constant is: `{code:FunctionName|Param}`
>
> The Pascal script can contain several functions which are called when
> Setup wants to know the value of a scripted `{code:...}` constant. *The
> called function must have 1 `String` parameter named `Param`*, and must
> return a `String` or a `Boolean` value depending on where the constant is
> used.
>
> The syntax of a `{code:...}` constant is: `{code:FunctionName|Param}`

It also provides:

- An example function:

```
[Code]
function MyConst(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{autopf}');
end;
```

- An example useage:

```
[INI]
FileName: "{app}\MyIni.ini"; Section: "MySettings"; Key: "ShortApp"; String: "{code:GetShortName|{app}}"
```

You don't have to use the parameter but it must be part of the prototype.

Comment: Seems I am still able to simply call {code:MethodName} without the parameter. Though you are correct about the (Param: String) needing to be necessary. it compiled after adding that.

Comment: @Tacitus86 Correct. That linked document says if you omit the | etc. that it will default to an empty string.